# RichFaces 4 fileupload clear and clear all buttons

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

Well currently I have this:

```
<rich:fileUpload addLabel="Agregar" clearAllLabel="Quitar todos"
                 clearLabel="Quitar" deleteLabel="Quitar"
                 doneLabel="Completado" uploadLabel="Subir archivos"
                 fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.doUpload}"
                 acceptedTypes="txt, csv"
                 noDuplicate="true">
    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="validationButton"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="clear" listener="#{uploadBean.doClearFilesList}"
              render="validationButton"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

On the backing bean I have a list of the files uploaded. When I click on `Clear/Clear all` button the event `clear` is fired and the method `doClearFilesList` (which just clears the list of files uploaded) is perfectly when the user hits the `Clear All` button, but If the user clicks on `Clear` button It should just delete the item on the list corresponding to the file cleared.

What can I do on my `UploadBean.doClearFilesList` method to delete a single file from the list? Should be something like:

```
public void doClearFilesList(){
    files.clear(); //when CLEAR ALL is clicked
    files.remove(oneFile); //when CLEAR is clicked
    validationButtonRendered = false;
}
```

Any idea?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

RichFaces 4.1.0 Final
JSF Mojarra 2.1.6
Tomcat 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not clear at which point you failed to run the sample described at https://community.jboss.org/message/727544#727544

However I hope following would work for you which is very similar to above sample.

**Page:**

```
<h:head>
<script>
  function clear(event) {
    var files = new Array();
    var data = event.rf.data;
    for (var i in data) {
      files[i] = data[i].name;
    }
    clearFunc(files);
  }
</script>
</h:head>
<body>
  <h:form>
    <rich:fileUpload onclear="clear(event);"/>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="clearFunc" action="#{del.clearFile}" ajaxSingle="true">
      <a4j:param name="fName" assignTo="#{del.fileNames}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
  </h:form>
</body>
```

**Class:**

```
public class Del {
  String[] fileNames;
  public void clearFile() {
    for(String name : fileNames) {
      System.out.println(">>" + name);
      //Do file removing part here
    }
  }
  public String[] getFileNames() {
    return fileNames;
  }
  public void setFileNames(String[] fileNames) {
    this.fileNames = fileNames;
  }
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful thanks. Just one more question, how can I know who was the caller of the `clearFile()` function? If it was the **Clear All** button or the **Clear** link?

Comment: I don't know why you need it, and sorry I don't have a proper answer for that. However in your Javascript function you can access the element which fired the event by calling "window.event.srcElement". Simply for ClearAll button "window.event.srcElement.tagName" returns 'SPAN' and for Delete link it returns 'A'. It means you can identify the component correctly in your javascript part. So after identifying the component try to pass it to the server by using the <a4j:jsFunction/>.

Answer (score 0):

Add "onclear" attribute to your <rich:fileUpload/> component and call a <a4j:jsFunction/> and pass the file name to it as below.

```
<rich:fileUpload onclear="clearFunc(event.memo.entry.fileName);" ..../>
```

Your <a4j:jsFunction/> should be as below.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="clearFunc" actionListener="#{uploadBean.clearFile}" ajaxSingle="true">
   <a4j:actionparam name="fName" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Inside the listener method you can access the file name as below.

```
public void clearFile(ActionEvent event) {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  String fileName = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("fName").toString();
  System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);}
```

Comment: Should the a4j:jsFunction be inside the fileUpload tag? like `<rich:fileUpload ... > <a4j:jsFunction ... />  <rich:fileUpload ... />` And how will I know if the clicked button was either **Clear all** or **Clear** ??

Comment: I'm currently using RichFaces 4.1.0 and theres no `<a4j:actionParam>` so I'm using `<a4j:param/>` is that ok?

Comment: Also tried with what this thread https://community.jboss.org/message/727544#727544 suggests but I can't get the filename, any idea?

Comment: Sorry BRabbit27. It seems 'event.memo.entry.fileName' doesn't give the file name in Richfaces 4.x.