# RichFaces fileupload clear and clear all

Tags: jsf, richfaces

The component `rich:fileUpload` supports `onclear` event, but I can't distinguish CLEAR event and CLEARALL event. The code:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{WF_Attachment_BB.uploadListener}"
    maxFilesQuantity="#{WF_Attachment_BB.availableQuantity}"
    autoclear="false"
    clearControlLabel="clear"
    clearAllControlLabel="clearAll"
    onclear="clearFunc()"
    id="upload" >
</rich:fileUpload>
<a4j:jsFunction id="clearFunc" name="clearFunc" ajaxSingle="true"
    actionListener="#{WF_Attachment_BB.clearUploadData}">
    <a4j:actionparam name="fName"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

I want to do this: when I click `clearControlLabel`, the `WF_Attachment_BB.clearUploadData` clears one from server and when I click `clearAllControlLabel`, the `WF_Attachment_BB.clearUploadData` clears all from server.

Comment: This might help: https://community.jboss.org/message/638802#638802

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RichFaces 4 fileupload clear and clear all buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935425/richfaces-4-fileupload-clear-and-clear-all-buttons). Add following line `onclear="alert(event.rf.data[0].name);"` in fileUpload component for testing clear event in RF4.x